# python - scrapy, one by one print

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on google search crawling

Here is my code

```
 def parse(self, response):
    all_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]')

    for page in all_page:
        title = page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/h3/div/text()').extract()
        link = page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/@href').extract()
        print('title', title)
        print('link', link)
```

output is

title ['iPhone - Compare Models - Apple', 'iPhone - Compare Models - Apple (MY)',......]

link[https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiKvsnnmLDxAhWZIDQIHXEdA60QFjAGegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1FCyWoMh1LcbM65W6l8ypN', '/url?q=https://www.apple.com/my/iphone/compare/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiKvsnnmLDxAhWZIDQIHXEdA60QFjAHegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3i33ED_sBrbAuNLAJsOlxe',....]

I want like this

title : 'iPhone - Compare Models - Apple'

Link : [https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiKvsnnmLDxAhWZIDQIHXEdA60QFjAGegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1FCyWoMh1LcbM65W6l8ypN'](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiKvsnnmLDxAhWZIDQIHXEdA60QFjAGegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1FCyWoMh1LcbM65W6l8ypN%27)

title : ''iPhone - Compare Models - Apple (MY)'

Link :[https://www.apple.com/my/iphone/compare/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiKvsnnmLDxAhWZIDQIHXEdA60QFjAHegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3i33ED_sBrbAuNLAJsOlxe'](https://www.apple.com/my/iphone/compare/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiKvsnnmLDxAhWZIDQIHXEdA60QFjAHegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3i33ED_sBrbAuNLAJsOlxe%27)

How to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `title` and `link` results are `list`s with several items, so you need to loop over them, in parallel with `zip` assuming you get one link per title.
It looks like it from your example, but make sure it is the case.

```py
def parse(self, response):
    all_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]')

    for page in all_page:
        titles = page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/h3/div/text()').extract()
        links = page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/@href').extract()
        for title, link in zip(titles, links):
            print (f"title: '{title}'\n\n"
                   f"Link: {link}")
```

Comment: thank you. It would be very help to me. Appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

`extract()` method of `xpath` extracts all items found by the search expression, so with `page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/h3/div/text()').extract()` you get all findings just for this element.
You can `zip` them together, as mentioned in another answer, but to be more precise you need to start from the parent object.

```
for page in all_page:
    for element in page.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div'):
        title = element.xpath('a/h3/div/text()'). extract_first()
        link = element.xpath('a/@href').extract_first()
        print('title', title)
        print('link', link)
```

Comment: It is useful for me. Thank you.